# Magento how to Google Analytics enhanced eCommerce Tracking

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, google-analytics, google

I am new to the Google Analytics world and would like to implement Google Analytics enhanced eCommerce Tracking on my magento 1.9.3.2 site. I am a little confused how to best set this up:

[image: Google analytics ecommerce]

How would I set these "funnel steps" up for my magento site?

Also, I have set-up the following goal:[image: goal][image: goals]

Would this be correct?

Update:

Looking at the funnel below for the goal you can see various drop-outs to other checkout pages and from place order clicked to exit 18 times! this seems odd.

[image: funnel 1]
[image: funnel 2]

Comment: you can add goolge tracking code in admin of magento

Comment: Indeed, I am also using Fooman extension. I am just wanting to know how to get enhanced ecommerce tracking setup for magento, and if my goals is set correctly.